# How to check how many fingers touch the screen in Android?

Tags: android, android-studio, touch, touch-event

How do I create a (globally accessible) variable that always contain the number of fingers touching the screen?

Thanks

```
 int counter;

         public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
         switch(event.getActionMasked()) { 
           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 

             `enter code here`
         break; 
         case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:

               `enter code here`

        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: 

          `enter code here`

         break;          
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:

           `enter code here`

        break; 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:  

            `enter code here




   }
     return true;  
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

check out `getPointerCount` method from `MotionEvent`

```
int counter;

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    counter = event.getPointerCount();
    switch(event.getActionMasked()) { // if still needed
    ...
```

Comment: in each "case" condition I should add:  counter= event.getPointerCount()?

Comment: no, you can use it at any point, even before `switch.. case` statement (check edit)